# How to distinguish error code?

Tags: swift3, alamofire

Due to some logic I have to cancel some requests.
In my code I have single place of Alamofire errors handling. 
How to distinguish the request's error code to skip such errors:

```
(lldb) po response.result.error.debugDescription
"Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 \"cancelled\"
```

I do not want to show to the user an error alert each time he/she cancelled some operations.

At `error` field we have only `debugDescription` field. But how I can determine that `Code`? Frankly speaking parsing `debugDescription` string looks like as a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
response.result.withError() { error in
    if let urlErr = error as? URLError {
        if urlErr.code == .cancelled {
            return
        }
    }
    // process all other errors
}
```